# error with this tikz example

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I m getting  an error will executing this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[below] {$O$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$A$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,2) node[right] {$B$};
    \draw (1,0) arc (0:45:1);
    \draw (22:1.3) node { $ \dfrac{\pi}{4} $ }
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Semicolon at the end of `\draw (22:1.3) node { $ \dfrac{\pi}{4} $ };`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says `\dfrac` is undefined. You need `\usepackage{amsmath}` for that. And then you need to end that `\draw` statement with a semicolon, so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath} % <-- added
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[below] {$O$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$A$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,2) node[right] {$B$};
    \draw (1,0) arc (0:45:1);
    \draw (22:1.3) node { $ \dfrac{\pi}{4} $ }; % <-- added semicolon
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}

\end{document}
```